# ImageProcessor seems to rotate image 90 degrees after resizing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, image-processing, image-uploading, imageprocessor

I downloaded the ImageProcessor library using nuget for c#.  I am using it to upload and resize image for a website.  The upload process works fine except, when I try to view the uploaded image it appears backward rotated 90 from the original image.  Here is the code that I am using:

```
        ISupportedImageFormat format = new JpegFormat { Quality = 70 };

        using (MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream(_img))
        {
            using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Initialize the ImageFactory using the overload to preserve EXIF metadata.
                using (ImageFactory imageFactory = new ImageFactory(preserveExifData: false))
                {
                    // Load, resize, set the format and quality and save an image.
                    imageFactory.Load(inStream)
                        .Resize(new ResizeLayer(new Size(width, height), resizeMode: resizeMode))
                                .Format(format)
                                .Save(outStream);
                }

                return outStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Depending on what software you are using to view the image, some software uses the image's meta-data to rotate the image - and the ImageProcessor might not. Or visa versa.

Comment: It is being viewed from a browser.  I downloaded the resized image and it was 90 degrees off.

Comment: Try setting the `preserveExifData` to `true` and see if it makes a difference. Other than that, I am out of suggestions. Sorry.

Comment: Now I do notice that the picture is actually long ways, don't know if that makes a difference.  I twas taken from a phone.

Comment: Photos normally have Exif meta data. One of those Exif properties is Orientation. This can affect how images are displayed. Try my above suggestion to see if it helps.

Comment: Here's a link to  a blog complaining about Orientation. It might prove enlightening. :) http://keyj.emphy.de/exif-orientation-rant/

Comment: If the ExIf meta data is the problem, how can I get around it?

Comment: If all the images are meant to be Landscape oriented then you could check if the image's height is greater than its width and if so, rotate the image.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this .... when i download a image from web then resize is proper and the image is not rotating but if i upload from my mobile it is rotating to 90 or 180 degree depending on the phone...

Answer (score 6):

If you are not preserving EXIF metadata the ImageFactory class has a method `AutoRotate` that will alter the image to compensate for the original orientation.

http://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor/imagefactory/autorotate/

Your new code would be as follows.

```
ISupportedImageFormat format = new JpegFormat { Quality = 70 };

using (MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream(_img))
{
    using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // Initialize the ImageFactory using the overload to preserve EXIF metadata.
        using (ImageFactory imageFactory = new ImageFactory(preserveExifData: false))
        {
            // Load, resize, set the format and quality and save an image.
            imageFactory.Load(inStream)
                        .AutoRotate()
                        .Resize(new ResizeLayer(new Size(width, height), resizeMode: resizeMode))
                        .Format(format)
                        .Save(outStream);
        }

        return outStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```